# How to change lat and long in iPhone 5 device to test an app

Tags: iphone

I want to test the app by changing the latitude and longitude of particular location, as I am residing in different location I want to make sure the App works fine in the supported geolocation.

I have tried changing the Language & Region but no luck. Other ways/ideas also appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter locations using `Simulator\Debug\Location`.
I don't remember a valid solution for a device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .gpx files to simulate custom lat/lng coordinates on iPhone